# Как добавить виртуальную топологию к ленточному методу умножения матриц

Tags: c++, mpi

У меня есть ленточный метод:
Алгоритм представляет собой итерационную процедуру, количество итераций которой совпадает с количеством подзадач. На каждой итерации алгоритма каждая подзадача содержит одинаковое количество строк матрицы А и матрицы В. При итерации осуществляется скалярное умножение строк, содержащихся в подзадачах, что приводит к получению соответствующих элементов результирующей матрицы C. По завершении вычислений в конце каждой итерации столбцы матрицы B должны быть перенесены между подзадачами так, чтобы каждая подзадача содержала новые столбцы матрицы B и можно было вычислить новые элементы матрицы C. В конце итераций строки собираются в единую матрицу C.
Топология гиперкуб, N = 2, но как перепроектировать этот метод, чтобы добавить виртуальную топологию. Как добавить топологию, нужно ли добавлять ее в метод или как связать топологию и умножение матриц.

```
void MatrixMultiplicationMPI(double *A, double *B,  double *C,int size)
{
   int i = 0, j = 0;
 
   double *bufA, *bufB, *bufC;
 
   int dim = size;
 
   MPI_Status Status;
 
   int ProcPartsize = dim/ProcNum;
 
   int ProcPartElem = ProcPartsize*dim;
 
   bufA = new double[ProcPartElem];
 
   bufB = new double[ProcPartElem];
 
   bufC = new double[ProcPartElem];
 
   for (i = 0; i < ProcPartElem; i++)
 
      bufC[i] = 0;
 
   MPI_Scatter(A, ProcPartElem, MPI_DOUBLE, bufA, ProcPartElem, MPI_DOUBLE,
               0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   MPI_Scatter(B, ProcPartElem, MPI_DOUBLE, bufB, ProcPartElem, MPI_DOUBLE,
               0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 
   int k = 0 ;
 
   int NextProc = ProcRank + 1;
 
   if ( ProcRank == ProcNum - 1 ) NextProc = 0;
 
   int PrevProc = ProcRank - 1;
 
   if ( ProcRank == 0 ) PrevProc = ProcNum - 1;
 
   int PrevDataNum = ProcRank;
 
   for (int p = 0; p < ProcNum; p++)
   {
      for (i = 0; i < ProcPartsize; i++)
         for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
         {
            double tmp = 0;
                  for (k = 0; k < ProcPartsize; k++)
                        tmp += bufA[PrevDataNum * ProcPartsize + i * size + k] * bufB[k * size + j];
 
              bufC[i * size + j] += tmp;
            }
      PrevDataNum -= 1;
 
      if (PrevDataNum < 0)
 
              PrevDataNum = ProcNum - 1;
 
      MPI_Sendrecv_replace(bufB, ProcPartElem, MPI_DOUBLE, NextProc, 0, PrevProc, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);
 
   }
   MPI_Gather(bufC, ProcPartElem, MPI_DOUBLE, C, ProcPartElem, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 
}
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что вы понимаете под топологией?

Comment: В MPI топология представляет собой механизм сопоставления процессам, принадлежащим группе, альтернативных по отношению к обычной схем нумерации

Comment: @gpg можете что-нибудь подсказать